# Pros and Cons of Kafka vs Rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, messagebroker, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream

Kafka and RabbitMQ are well known message brokers. I want to build a microservice with Spring Boot and it seems that Spring Cloud provides out of the box solutions for them as the defacto choices. I know a bit of the trayectory of RabbitMQ which has lot of support. Kafka belongs to Apache so it should be good. So whats the main goal difference between RabbitMQ and Kafka? Take in consideration this will be used with Spring Cloud. Please share your experiences and criteria. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three application level difference is:

1. Kafka supports re-read of consumed messages while rabbitMQ
   not.
2. Kafka supports ordering of messages in partition while rabbitMQ
   supports it with some constraint such as one exchange routing
   to the queue,one queue, one consumer to queue.
3. Kafka is for fast in publishing data to partition than rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 5):

I certainly wouldn't consider Kafka as lightweight. Kafka relies on ZooKeeper so you'd need to throw ZooKeeper to your stack as well.

Kafka is pubsub but you could re-read messages. If you need to process large volumes of data, Kafka performs much better and its synergy with other big-data tools is a lot better. It specifically targets big data.

Comment: And What about RabbitMQ? Pros and Cons remember.

Comment: Update as of 2020, Confluent is planning to remove Zookeeper from Kafka
https://www.confluent.io/blog/removing-zookeeper-dependency-in-kafka/

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is more than just a pub/sub messaging platform. It also includes APIs for data integration (Kafka Connect) and stream processing (Kafka Streams). These higher level APIs make developers more productive versus using only lower level pub/sub messaging APIs.

Also Kafka has just added Exactly Once Semantics in June 2017 which is another differentiator.

Answer (score 0):

To start with Kafka does more than what RabbitMQ does. Message broker is just one subset of Kafka but Kafka can also act as Message storage and Stream processing. Comparing just the Message broker part, again Kafka is more robust than RabbitMQ as it supports Replication (for availability) and partitioning (for scalability), Replay of messages (if needed to reprocess) and it is Pull based. RabbitMQ can be scalable by using multiple consumers for a given queue but again it is push based and you lose ordering among multiple consumers.

It all depends on the use case and your question doesn't provide the use case and performance requirements to suggest one over other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice answer in this youtube video [Apache Kafka Explained (Comprehensive Overview)](https://youtu.be/JalUUBKdcA0?t=1014).
It basically says that the difference between Kafka and standard [JMS](http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/publico/mens-2010-11/sesion01-apuntes.html) systems like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ it that

- Kafka consumers pull the messages from the brokers which allows for buffering messages for as long as the retention period holds. While in most JMS systems messages are pushed to the consumers which make strategies like [back-pressure](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Back-Pressure) harder to achieve.
- Kafka also eases the replacement of events by storing them on disk, so they can be replaced at any time.
- Kafka guarantees the ordering of message within a partition.
- Kafka overall provides an easy way for building scalable and fault-tolerant systems.
- Kafka requires is more complex and harder to understand than JMS systems.